# Can't seem to reduce memory usage of my Android App, 5 AsyncTasks won't close

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

I've produced an Android application and I'm rather happy with the functionality etc. i.e. minimal amount of bugs, so I've begun looking into ways I can reduce the memory requirements of the application.

During the application I make use of a number of AsyncTasks each of which seem to be performing their desired functions very well and at the conclusion to be certain they've closed I even add *this.cancel(true);* or *Async1.cancel(true);* etc.

At certain points during the usage of my Android application, it simply doesn't do anything whilst we wait for the usage to press a button etc, at these times there shouldn't be any tasks running in the background (as described above).

But I've noticed by utilising the Android Studio debugger that 5 AsyncTasks aren't closing even though their assigned tasks are complete and I've also explicitly requested them to close at the completion of these tasks.

To be clear these Async tasks have not been instructed to wait for a particular event etc. I have explicitly told them to close.

And here is a dump of the debugging:

Full thread dump

```
"AsyncTask #1@4076" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks AsyncTask #1@4076
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x100a> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"AsyncTask #2@4085" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks AsyncTask #2@4085
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x100b> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"AsyncTask #3@4088" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks AsyncTask #3@4088
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x100c> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"AsyncTask #4@4091" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks AsyncTask #4@4091
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x100d> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"AsyncTask #5@4092" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks AsyncTask #5@4092
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x100e> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerDaemon@4070" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FinalizerDaemon@4070
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
      - locked <0x1008> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"main@4067" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-1)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@4071" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@4071
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:255)
      - locked <0x1009> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:227)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon@4069" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks ReferenceQueueDaemon@4069
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:147)
      - locked <0xc38> (a java.lang.Class)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Timer-0@4075" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks Timer-0@4075
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423)
      at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:238)
      - locked <0xfeb> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)

"HeapTaskDaemon@4072" daemon prio=5 waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:355)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Signal Catcher@4068" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder_1@4073" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder_2@4074" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"RenderThread@4077" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"hwuiTask1@4078" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"hwuiTask2@4079" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder_3@4100" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended
```

To be clear I'm wanting to close these AsyncTasks and any other unnecessary background items regarding my application.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ExecutorService may reuse AsyncTask's, when task is finished, it back to executor queue and may be used second time in next call.

To see this effect build simple app that runs some operations in AsyncTask several times, then You may see something similar to posted thread dump.